# reverse date javascript from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, html, date, reverse

I making an asp project and the date is displayed as yyyy/mm/dd but when the user press on the edit button for the form i need to replace the date format with dd/mm/yyyy

this the asp code remember i need the user to show the date as yyyy/mm/dd in the table but when he pressing on a button i need the date to be reversed to dd/mm/yyyy

```
 <td class="hidden-phone">@EnnotaBAL.ArabicEncoding.GetArabicNumbers(transaction.PostDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))</td>
```

and this the javascript code for the date element:

```
// Transaction Date
var TransDate = oCells.item(4).innerHTML;
document.getElementById('Date').value = convertDigitIn(TransDate);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
function convertDigitIn(str){
   return str.split('/').reverse().join('/');
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be simple

Comment: @adeneo 40 seconds exactly between asking and answering. No edit :)

Comment: Thanx man for your help: i fixed it by using this command          TransDate = TransDate.split('/').reverse().join('/');